# Unrecognized variable in event handler

Tags: vba, excel

In the event handler (click) I can't get the program to recognize variable j (it's local).
When it gets to the line `check.Value = MyCheck & j.Value` it returns 'Mycheck1' only, even though it's in a loop.

I need the program to go through all of the check buttons and check if they are chosen. 
Does anybody know the right syntax?

Main sub:

```
With TempForm.CodeModule
    ' ** Add/change next 5 lines' This code adds the commands/event handlers
    ' to the form
    X = .CountOfLines
    .InsertLines X + 1, "Sub CommandButton1_Click()"
    .InsertLines X + 2, "Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset"
    .InsertLines X + 3, "Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset"
    .InsertLines X + 4, "Dim i As Integer"
    .InsertLines X + 5, "Dim ran as string"
    .InsertLines X + 6, "j = 1 "
    .InsertLines X + 7, "set rs = Rsfun"
    .InsertLines X + 8, "Do While Not rs.EOF"
    '.InsertLines X + 8, "For j = " & i & " To rs.MaxRecords"
    '.InsertLines X + 9, "" & i & " = " & i & " +1"
    .InsertLines X + 9, "Dim check As MSForms.CheckBox "
    .InsertLines X + 10, "Set check = UserForm1.Controls.Add(""Forms.checkbox.1"")"
    .InsertLines X + 11, "check = MyCheck & j"
    .InsertLines X + 12, "If Check.value = true then"
    .InsertLines X + 13, "ran = ""A" & i & ""
    .InsertLines X + 14, "MsgBox (ran)"
    .InsertLines X + 15, "range(ran).value= rs.Fields(0)"
    .InsertLines X + 16, "End If"
    .InsertLines X + 17, "RS.MoveNext"
    .InsertLines X + 18, "j= j+1"
    .InsertLines X + 19, "Loop"
    .InsertLines X + 20, "Unload Me"
    .InsertLines X + 21, "End Sub"
    End With
```

Event handler:

```
    Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim ran As String
    j = 1
    Set rs = Rsfun
    Do While Not rs.EOF
    Dim check As MSForms.CheckBox
    Set check = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.checkbox.1")
    check.Value = MyCheck & j.Value
    If check.Value = True Then
    ran = "A1"
    MsgBox (ran)
    range(ran).Value = rs.Fields(0)
    End If
    j = j + 1
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    Unload Me
    End Sub
```

Comment: and what are you using `j` for? what is the error? how do you know, it is not recognized?

Comment: what i neen is that the program go throw all of the check buttons and check if they are chosen. now the program only check with the first check button (MyCheck1) and for some reason don't continue to check with the rest.

Comment: Where does your recordset `rs` gets the record from? Looking at the code, it is missing the part where it will fetch the data from some source.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `check.Value = MyCheck & j.Value` you need to

```
check.Value = UserForm1.Controls(MyCheck & j).Value
```

Another thing with:

```
Set check = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.checkbox.1")
```

will add your cb to upper left corner and next one will cover previous.
Maybe after adding you want to move it just a little bit like
`check.top = j * 15`

Good luck.